# Java External Class Loading ClassDefNotFoundError

Tags: java, jar, external, compile-time

So for the mod I'm writing, you have the ability to program your own perks to be used by your character. These perks are compiled and then put into a folder called "perks". I created an Abstract Class that is to be extended by all of these external perks, and it is held in the main jar.

Perk Abstract Class:

```
public abstract class Perk {

    public abstract void onCall( RCPlayer caller );

}
```

Example Perk:

```
public class ExamplePerk extends Perk {

    public void onCall( RCPlayer ) {
        // do something...
    }

}
```

The method I use for loading in these external Jars.
I've stripped out all of the null checks and try/catch statements to keep clean.

```
private static LoadStatus loadPerk( String path ) {
    URL url = new File( path ).toURI().toURL();

    URL[] urls = new URL[]{ url };
    YamlConfiguration perkYML = null;

    ClassLoader cl = new URLClassLoader( urls );
    Class<?> cls = Class.forName( main /* class path */, true, cl );
    clazz = cls.asSubclass( Perk.class );

    // Instantiate class & put into a data structure
    perks.put( new Descriptor( main, name, id, description ), clazz.newInstance() );
}
```

Full error: https://gyazo.com/e10acb615d88c50480a57118d54a3b17

It is throwing a ClassNoDefFoundError because it cannot find the "Perk" abstract class.

My question is, how do I specify at runtime where the Perk class is located? At compile time I just add the library, but when it comes time to use the Perk class as an extension, the program flops and throws this error.

If I add the whole main jar to the perks folder, it does work. However this is bad practice as I would have to include all of the project files & it would be a mess.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't working because it's trying to instantiate an abstract class which is not possible.

See this link - you need a reference to the actual subclass.

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/class_assubclass.htm

Comment: I see what you mean, I've now instantiated the class as it is and use a cast after the instantiation. This fixed the first problem, however I still am unable to get the class as it throws a NoClassDefFoundError.

Answer (score 1):

Trying explicitly mentioning the parent classloader for perks impls.
ClassLoader cl = new URLClassLoader( urls, Perk.class.getClassLoader() );

Most probably Perk.class is not loaded by ThreadContext classloader.